# Track progress of functions running Python Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, progress-bar

I need to implement a live progress control using python.

I have some long running functions, is there a way to get the Total Count of required for that function to execute which will help me to count the progress percentage based on Total Count.

Example: 1% out of 100
2% out of 100
'
'
'
99% out of 100

I am not understanding how to get the total_count at one place which will help me to analyse how much time will a function take to complete its execution.

Comment: Is it possible to add the tasks inside an array and keep tracking of those tasks using the array?

Comment: So you are trying to say like whatever might be the task that gets triggered add that into an array and keep watching.

Comment: Yes... I'm assuming you are using python threads or python multiprocessing to create the tasks